# In Django the error is, TypeError at /Hod/Student/Add 'Course' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qBDd.png)

```
Even if I change the  course = Course.objects.get(id = course_id) to  course = Course.objects.filter(id = course_id) there seems no error thrown but the message does not get printed that 'Student added successfully'.
```

```
**Hod_views.py**
Even if I change the  course = Course.objects.get(id = course_id) to  course = Course.objects.filter(id = course_id) there seems no error thrown but the message does not get printed that 'Student added successfully'.

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from app.models import Course, Session_Year, CustomUser, Student
from django.contrib import messages

@login_required(login_url="/")
def HOME(request):
    return render(request, "Hod/home.html")

@login_required(login_url="/")
def ADD_STUDENT(request):
    course = Course.objects.all()
    session_year = Session_Year.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        profile_pic = request.FILES.get('profile_pic')
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        gender = request.POST.get('gender')
        course_id = request.POST.get('course_id')
        session_year_id = request.POST.get('session_year_id')

        if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.warning(request, "Email Is Already Taken!")
            return redirect('add_student')

        if CustomUser.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            messages.warning(request, "Username Is Already Taken!")
            return redirect('add_student')

        else:
            user = CustomUser(
                first_name = first_name,
                last_name = last_name,
                username = username,
                email = email,
                profile_pic = profile_pic,
                user_type = 3
            )
            user.set_password = password
            user.save()

            course = Course.objects.get(id = course_id)
            session_year = Session_Year.objects.get(id = session_year_id)
            student = Student(
                admin = user,
                address = address,
                session_year_id = session_year,
                course_id = course,
                gender = gender,
            )
            student.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Student Successfully Saved!')
            redirect('add_student')

    context = {
        "course" : course,
        "session_year" : session_year,
    }
    return render(request, "Hod/add_student.html", context)
```

```
**Models.py:**
Even if I change the  course = Course.objects.get(id = course_id) to  course = Course.objects.filter(id = course_id) there seems no error thrown but the message does not get printed that 'Student added successfully'.

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    USER = (
        (1,'HOD'),
        (2,'STAFF'),
        (3,'STUDENT')
    )
    user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER,max_length=50,default=1)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/profile_pic')

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Session_Year(models.Model):
    session_start = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    session_end = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.session_start + " To " + self.session_end

class Student(models.Model):
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.TextField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    course_id = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    session_year_id = models.ForeignKey(Session_Year, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.admin.first_name + " " + self.admin.last_name
```

```
add_student.html:
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form method="post" action="{% url 'add_student' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <h5 class="form-title"><strong><span>Add Student</span></strong></h5>
                    </div>
                    {% if messages %}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                    {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
                    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                        {{message}}
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if messages %}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                    {% if message.tags == 'success' %}
                    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                        {{message}}
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                    <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Profile Picture</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="profile_pic">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="address"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label>Gender</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="gender">
                                <option>Select Gender</option>
                                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                <option value="Others">Others</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label>Course</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="course_id">
                                <option>Select Course</option>
                                {% for i in course %}
                                <option value="{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label>Session Year</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="session_year_id">
                                <option>Select Session Year</option>
                                {% for i in session_year %}
                                <option value="{{i.id}}">{{i.session_start}} To {{i.session_end}}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Student</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Change `redirect('add_student')` to `return redirect('add_student')`